# How do modern cheap multimeters survive a massive range of voltages?

Tags: multimeter, over-voltage-protection

I bought a little, rubbish multimeter for $2. If I set the voltage range to 200 millivolt, then stick the probes into a mains socket, all I'll see is "1" on the display indicating measurement out of range. It's not so many years back when doing the same with a regular multimeter (without setting it to 500V range first) would result in a small explosion, blown fuse for that socket's circuit, and multimeter on fire.

What tricks do these multimeters use to be able to measure voltages this low but still survive voltages this high?

Comment: Can you share with us the exact make and model number of this device ?

Comment: I'm sure that you will get some good responses here. In addition, you can search "multimeter teardown" on https://www.youtube.com/@EEVblog for lots of interesting examples for various manufacturers...  As well as Dave developing his own version.  Better link?: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4F0B97C59B1D2509

Comment: @citizen The case claims DT830B but I wouldn't trust it. Photos of DT830B don't quite match (all-black plastic, two halves of the case don't fit well with each other), all offers I see are at least twice what I paid, it came without any box or manual, quality-wise it's not bottom shelf, it's on the floor under the bottom shelf. The 9V battery it takes was more expensive. Oh, and free shipping from Aliexpress (package shared with 2 other similarly priced items).

Answer (score 2):

1. Multimeter inputs are high impedance only in mild overrange conditions. Once the voltage is much higher, they become low impedance.
2. A clamping circuit limits the voltages on the sensitive internal nodes in the meter.
3. Positive temperature coefficient (PTC) impedances, as well as fusible resistors, are put between the input terminals and the clamps, preventing clamps from being overloaded.

When the voltage is in-range, the currents flowing through the PTCs and protective resistances are minuscule. The PTCs stay cool, and don't affect operation much. When the voltage is high enough to trigger the clamps, high current starts to flow, limited somewhat by the series resistors. The PTCs are initially cold and look like shorts. But the PTCs then heat up due to high current, increase their resistance, and eventually end up in a thermal equilibrium: they stay hot and limit current.

In the cost range and performance suitable for meter duty, reliable PTCs  have only been available IIRC since the late 70s, and even then only in higher-end meters first.